# If $X$ is compact and connected then what can be said about $X/\sim$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

If $X$ is compact and connected will the quotient space $X/\sim$ have any special properties given $\sim$is an equivalence relation? Especially, can it be Hausdorff?

Answer (score 0):

Of course $X/\sim$ is also compact and connected as a continuous image of $X$.

[In this question and its answer and comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1093373/4280) you'll find a characterisation when $Y$ will be Hausdorff when $X$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Since a quotient map is, by construction, continuous, the image of a compact, connected space will be compact, though not necessarily Hausdorff. An example of this last is the quotient $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Q $ , with $\mathbb Q$ as additive subgroup..

Answer (score 0):

Quotient (or even an image) of a connected space is connected.

Quotient (or even an image) of a compact space is compact. Here compactness means "every cover has a finite subcover". Some authors define compact space to be Hausdorff, we don't assume that here.

Quotient of a Hausdorff space need not be Hausdorff, even when the initial space is both compact and connected, e.g. $[0,1]/\sim$ where $x\sim y$ iff $x=y$ or $x,y\in(0,1)$. The quotient space is homeomorphic to $\{a,b,c\}$ with topology $\big\{\emptyset, \{b\}, \{a,b\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\big\}$ which is not Hausdorff.

> Especially, can it be Hausdorff?

Yes, it can, see this: [$X/\sim$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\sim$ is closed in $X \times X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91639/x-sim-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-sim-is-closed-in-x-times-x)