# Adjunction spaces being Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I was asked the following question about a set $X$ being Hausdorff.

> If $X=A\cup B$ where $A,B$ are closed and Hausdorff (as subspaces). Show that $X$ is Hausdorff.

I was able to prove it directly using sets but my first thought was using adjunction spaces. I had the following problem earlier which I solved which said:

> If $X=C\cup D$ where $C,D$ are closed and cover $X$, we form the adjunction space along their intersection (the inclusion map), then we get a homeomorphism between $(C\amalg D/\sim)=C\cup_{C\cap D}D\cong X$.

So for my original problem to show that $X=A\cup B$. We know that $A\amalg B$ is Hausdorff so I want to show that $(A\amalg B)/\sim$ is Hausdorff. However, I have read that it is not always true that a quotient space is Hausdorff. One question I have is when will a quotient space be Hausdorff and another question is other neat ways to solve my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x, y \in A \cup B$. If both $x,y \in A$, then they have disjoint neighborhoods because $A$ is Hausdorff. Similarly if $x,y \in B$. If neither of these cases apply, then $A \setminus B$ and $B \setminus A$ are disjoint neighborhoods of the points.

Your more general question, when will a quotient space $X/\sim$ be Hausdorff, is trickier. A necessary condition is for the set $\sim\, \subset X^2$ defining the relation to be closed, which in particular implies that each equivalence class is closed. If the quotient map is open, then that is also sufficient (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91639/x-sim-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-sim-is-closed-in-x-times-x)). It is also sufficient if $X$ is compact Hausdorff (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093373/question-about-quotient-of-a-compact-hausdorff-space)). Quotients of Hausdorff spaces by actions of compact groups are always Hausdorff (as quotients by group actions are always open).