# The product of quotient spaces is a quotient space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. 
Now define an equivalence relation $\approx$ on $X \times X $ by $ [(x,y)]_\approx = [x]_\sim \times[y]_\sim $

Is it true that  $X/\sim \times $ $X/\sim $ $ \cong (X\times X)/\approx $ ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228687 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820943

Answer (score 1):

$[x]_\sim \times [y]_\sim$ and $[(x,y)]_\approx$ as sets are bijective. In one case you first take the projection to the cosets, and then the product. In the other you first take the product and then project to the cosets defined with the above equivalence independantly on the two components.

I'm assuming you want to check if the induced topology is the same.

It is straightforward that any open set in $\tau$ is mapped to the "same" set in the two spaces which is how their topology is induced therefore they are homeomorphic.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph: the sets $[x]_{∼} × [y]_{∼}$ and $[(x, y)]_{≈}$ are equal (by definition). I suspect you mean instead that $(X/{∼}) × (Y/{∼})$ and $(X × Y)/{≈}$ are bijective. Regard the third paragraph: the resulting spaces are _not_ always homeomorphic. Your ‘argument’ doesn’t make sense, since the quotient topology and product topology are not defined by taking images of open sets.