# Are quotients of topological categories also topological categories?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I am considering quotients of categories as in MacLane's *Categories for the working mathematician*, as described in the next paragraph.

Let $C$ be a (small) category and $R$ an equivalence relation on (the arrows of) $C$ such that the domain and range maps are invariant on $R$-equivalence classes (i.e., if two arrows are equivalent then they have same domain and range). Assume further that $R$ is a congruence: $f_1Rg_1$ and $f_2Rg_2$ implies $f_1f_2Rg_1g_2$ whenever that makes sense. Then $C/R$ is a category (with same object space $Ob(C/R)=Ob(C)$ as $C$).

Assume further that $C$ is a *topological category*: $C$ and $Ob(C)$ are endowed with topologies making all structural maps continuous. Endow $C/R$ with the quotient topology.

> Is $C/R$ a topological category?

It is quite clear that the domain, range, and unit maps are continuous, however the composition is not clear because *$C/R\times C/R$ does not necessarily have the quotient topology of $C\times C$* (under the obvious map). See "[Products of quotient topology same as quotient of product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228687/products-of-quotient-topology-same-as-quotient-of-product-topology)".

[Ronnie Brown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28586/ronnie-brown) and J. P. L. Hardy have proven that the category of topological categories has quotients in the categorical sense (satisfying the universal property) in [this article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0412333), but the underlying category of this quotient is not necessarily $C/R$ as defined above.

Comment: So is a topological category a subcategory of the category of all topological spaces and all continuous maps?

Comment: @PaulFrost Not at all. There is no natural topology on the set of all topological spaces. A topological category is a category internal to topological spaces, not a subcategory thereof.