# Product of quotient topology not homeomorphic to the quotient of product topology

Tags: general-topology

How can I construct a counter-example for the following statement: if $\sim_X$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, $\sim_Y$ is an equivalence relation on $Y$, then $X/{\sim_X} \times Y/{\sim_Y}$ is homeomorphic to $(X \times Y)/{\sim_{XY}}$ where $(x_1,y_1) \sim_{XY} (x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1 \sim_X x_2$ and $y_1 \sim_Y y_2$?

There is a related question on this, [Products of quotient topology same as quotient of product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228687/products-of-quotient-topology-same-as-quotient-of-product-topology) , which says that it is false that if $p : X \to Z_1$ and $q : Y \to Z_2$ are quotient maps, then $p \times q$ is necessarily a quotient map. However, that this particular map is not a quotient map doesn't imply that an homeomorphism cannot be constructed.

Answer (score -2):

This answer is incorrect, and does not contribute to answering the posted question. Don't read it, and if you do, keep in mind it only illustrates how one could make a mistake.

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ with $0\sim1$. Then $X/\sim$ and $Y/\sim$ each is homeomorphic to a circle, so their product is a torus. On the other hand $(X\times Y)/\sim$
is a square with the four corners identified, which is not homeomorphic to a torus.

Edit to address the comment below.
Take a handkerchief and lift the four corners, bending it, so they touch. (But, apart from the corners meeting at a single point, the edges do not touch.) This is $(X\times Y)/\sim$.
Here is a more formal justification that there is no homeomorphism between $(X/\sim)\times(Y/\sim)$ (a torus) and $(X\times Y)/\sim$.
Removing one point from $(X\times Y)/\sim$ - the point where the corners of the handkerchief touch - leaves a simply connected space (a closed square with the four corners removed). There is no point with this property on the torus.

Comment: This is a good "intuitive" answer, but I was interested in a more formal answer. I'd like to formally show the impossibility of the homemorphism, as I do not have much intuition on the big quotient or what particular properties of this two spaces I could use (I guess I could go for the fundamental groups, but calculating it for $(X \times Y)/{\sim}$ seems to be hard).

Comment: @Fix It is not difficult to complete the proof formally. If you remove one point (the corner point) from $(X \times Y)/{\sim}$ you are left with a simply connected space (a closed square with the four corners removed). There is no point with this property on the torus.

Comment: The above answer isn't quite correct. Since $(x,0)\sim (x,1)$

Comment: @Tom. You are right, my example isn't quite correct, or rather not correct at all (though it took a year for my error to be pointed out, so I will leave it is it, just adding this comment). Indeed, $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$ and $(0,y)\sim(1,y)$ (in particular, $(0,0)\sim(0,1)\sim(1,1)\sim(1,0)$), so it looks like $(X\times Y)/\sim$ is a torus, just like $(X/\sim)\times(Y/\sim)$.