# Characterizing simply connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A topological space $X$ is *simply connected* if it is pathwise connected and each closed path $u : I = [0,1] \to X$ is path homotopic to the constant path at $x_0 = u(0) = u(1)$.

Recall that

1. A *closed path* $u$ is one with $u(0) = u(1)$. A closed path will also be called a *loop* and we write $\mathcal L'(X)$ for the set of all loops in $X$. If we want to be more precise, we say $u$ is a loop *based at $x_0 \in X$* provided $x_0 = u(0) = u(1)$. By  $\mathcal L'(X,x_0)$ we denote the set of all loops in $X$ which are based at $x_0$. Also note that each constant path is a loop.
2. Two paths  $u, v : I \to X$ with the same initial point $x_0 = u(0) = v(0)$ and the same terminal point $x_1 = u(1) = v(1)$ are *path homotopic*, $u \simeq_p v$, if there exists a  homotopy $H : I \times I \to X$ such that $H(t,0) = u(t)$ and $H(t,1) = v(t)$ for all $t$ and $H(0,s) = x_0, H(1,s) = x_1$ for all $s$ (such a homotopy $H$ is *stationary on the boundary $\partial I = \{0,1\}$*; it is called a *path homotopy*). It is well-known that $\simeq_p$  is an equivalence relation on the set $\mathcal P(X)$ of all paths in $X$. Clearly $\simeq_p$ restricts to an equivalence relation on $\mathcal L'(X)$ and to an equivalence relation on each $\mathcal L'(X,x_0)$.
3. The set of equivalence classes $\mathcal L'(X,x_0)/\simeq_p$ is nothing else than the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ with base point $x_0$.

**Question:** Find a list, as complete as possible, of properties characterizing topological spaces which are simply connected.

Each of these properties can then be taken as an alternative definition of *simply connected*.

Note that many questions in this forum deal with aspects of simple connectedness. The answer to the present question will hopefully cover most of them.

Comment: A superfluous by quite neat characterisation for a space $X$ to be simply connected is that it admit no essential map $K\rightarrow X$ from a CW complex $K$ of dimension $\leq 1$. Clearly this includes the cases $K=S^0,S^1$, and so neatly avoids having to explicitly mention paths at all. Of course you can formulate this instead with simplicial complexes, etc...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3117361.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The concept of a loop plays an essential role to characterize simple connectedness. Let us begin by introducing an equivalence relation for loops $u, v \in \mathcal L'(X)$ which is coarser than path homotopy. Recall that $u \simeq_p v$ requires that $u, v$ are based at the same point $x_0 \in X$ and $H : u \simeq_p v$ is stationary on $\{0,1\}$.

Given loops $u,v \in \mathcal L'(X)$, a *loop homotopy* is a homotopy $H : I \times I \to X$ from $u$ to $v$ such that for each $s \in I$ the map $H_s : I \to X, H_s(t) = H(t,s)$, is a loop. In that case we say that $u,v$ are *loop homotopic*,  $u \simeq_l v$. Clearly $\simeq_l$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal L'(X)$ and $u \simeq_p v$ implies $u \simeq_l v$.

Let us next give an alternative interpretation of a loop.

Loops can be identified with maps $S^1 \to X$ living on the circle $S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb C : \lvert z \rvert = 1 \}$. In fact, let $\mathcal L(X)$ denote the set of all these maps (which is denoted as the *free loop space of $X$*) and let $\exp : I \to S^1, \exp(t) = e^{2\pi i t} = \cos(2\pi t) + i \sin(2\pi t)$. This is a closed surjection, hence a quotient map. For $t, t' \in I$ we have $\exp(t) = \exp(t')$ if and only if $t = t'$ or $\{t, t'\} = \{0 ,1 \}$. Thus it identifies $0,1 \in I$ to a single point. Therefore $\exp^* : \mathcal L(X) \to \mathcal L'(X), \exp^*(f) = f \circ \exp$, is a bijection. To $S^1$ we give $1$ as a basepoint and say that $f : S^1 \to X$ is *based at $x_0 \in X$* if $f(1) = x_0$.

Under this bijection loop homotopy in $\mathcal L'(X)$ corresponds to ordinary homotopy of maps in $\mathcal L(X)$. Path homotopy in $\mathcal L'(X)$ corresponds to *basepoint-preserving homotopy in $\mathcal L(X)$*, where a basepoint-preserving homotopy is required to be stationary on the basepoint $1 \in S^1$. This is true because the map  $\exp \times id_I : I \times I  \to S^1 \times I$ is a closed surjection and thus a quotient map.

Here are our results.

For a path-connected space $X$ the following are equivalent:

|  | Path form | Circle form |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Each loop $u : I \to X$ is path homotopic to the constant loop based at $x_0 = u(0) = u(1)$. | Each $f : S^1 \to X$ is basepoint-preserving homotopic to the constant map based at $x_0 = f(1)$. |
| 2 | Any two loops $u, v : I \to X$ based at the same $x_0 \in X$ are path homotopic. | Any two $f, g : S^1 \to X$ based at the same $x_0 \in X$ are basepoint-preserving homotopic. |
| 3 | Any two paths $u, v : I \to X$ with the same endpoints are path homotopic. |  |
| 4 | Each loop $u : I \to X$ is loop homotopic to a constant loop in $X$. | Each $f : S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a constant map $S^1 \to X$. |
| 5 | Each loop $u : I \to X$ and each constant loop in $X$ are loop homotopic. | Each $f : S^1 \to X$ and each constant map $S^1 \to X$ are homotopic. |
| 6 |  | Each $f : S^1 \to X$ has a continuous extension $F : D^2 \to X$. |

For an arbitrary space $X$ simple connectedness is equivalent to each of the following properties:

|  | Path form | Circle form |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Each loop $u : I \to X$ and each constant loop in $X$ are loop homotopic. | Each $f : S^1 \to X$ and each constant map $S^1 \to X$ are homotopic. |
| 8 | Any two loops $u, v : I \to X$ are loop homotopic. | Any two $f, g : S^1 \to X$ are homotopic. |

It is clear that path and circle form in the same line are equivalent.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) : Obvious, (1) is a special case of (2).

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) : This follows from the fact that $\simeq_p$ is an equivalence relation.

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (4) : Obvious, (4) is a special case of (2).

(4) $\Rightarrow$ (5) : Obvious, in a path connected space any two constant maps $S^1 \to X$ are homotopic.

(5) $\Rightarrow$ (4) : Obvious, pick any constant map $S^1 \to X$.

(4) $\Rightarrow$ (6) : Let $H : S^1 \times I  \to X$ be a homotopy such that $H_0 = f$ and $H_1 = c$, where $c$ is a constant map (with value $x_0 \in X$). The map $p : S^1 \times I \to D^2, p(z,t) = (1-t)z$, is a closed surjection, hence a quotient map. It maps $S^1 \times \{1\}$ to $0 \in D^2$. Therefore $H$ induces a unique function $F : D^2 \to X$ such that $F \circ p = H$. Note that $F(z) = H(z/\lvert z \rvert,1 - \lvert z \rvert)$ for $z \ne 0$ and $H'(0) = x_0$. By the universal property of quotient maps, $F$ is continuous. For $z \in S^1$ we have $F(z) = H(z,0) = f(z)$, thus $F$ is the desired continuous extension of $f$.

(6) $\Rightarrow$ (1) : Let $F : D^2 \to X$ be a continuous extension of $f$. Define $H : S^1 \times I \to X, H(z,t) = F((1-t)z +t)$. This is a well-defined continuous map (note that $\lvert (1-t)z +t \rvert \le (1-t)\lvert z  \rvert + t = 1 - t + t = 1$). We have $H(z,0) = F(z) = f(z), H(z,1) = F(1) = f(1) = x_0$ and $H(1,t) = F(1) = f(1) = x_0$.

(3) $\Rightarrow$ (2) : Obvious, (2) is a special case of (3).

(6) $\Rightarrow$ (3) : Let $x_0 = u(0) = v(0)$ and $x_1 = u(1) = v(1)$. Let $S = I \times \{0,1\} \cup \{0,1\} \times I$ denote the boundary of the square $D = I \times I$. Points of $S$ will be written in the form $(t,s)$. Define
$$\phi : S  \to X, \begin{cases} u(t) & s = 0 \\ v(t) & s = 1 \\ x_0 & t = 0 \\ x_1 & t = 1  \end{cases}$$
Our aim is to find a continuous extension $H : D \to X$ of $\phi$; this is the desired path homotopy from $u$ to $v$. To do so, it suffices to find a homeomorphism $h : D \to D^2$ such that $h(S) = S^1$; then (6) can be applied to find a continuous extension $F : D^2 \to X$ of $f = \phi \circ h^{-1}$. Then clearly $H = F \circ h$ is the desired extension of $\phi$. The existence of such $h$ is well-known. We shall nevertheless give a proof in the end of this answer.

Let us now come to the characterizations (7) and (8) of simple connectedness.

If $X$ is simply connected, then it is path connected and (5) shows that (7) is satisfied. Conversely, let (7) be satisfied and let $a, b \in X$. The constant loops based at $a$ and $b$ are loop homotopic via a homotopy $H: I \times I \to X$. Then $u(s) = H(0,s)$ is a path from $a$ to $b$. This means that $X$ is path connected and satisfies (5), hence it also satisfies (1) and is therefore simply connected.

(7) $\Rightarrow$ (8) : Obvious because loop homotopy is an equivalence relation.

(8) $\Rightarrow$ (7) : Obvious, (7) is a special case of (8).

For the sake of completeness we finally construct a homeomorphism $h : D \to D^2$ such that $h(S) = S^1$.

Let $J = [-1,1]$ and $\alpha : I \to J, \alpha(t) = 2t - 1$. This is a homeomorphism; hence $\beta = \alpha \times \alpha : D \to \bar D = J \times J$ is a homeomorphism such that $\beta(S) = \bar S =  J \times \{-1,1\} \cup \{-1,1\} \times J = $ boundary of $\bar D$. Note that $\bar D = \{ (t,s) \in \mathbb R^2 : \lVert (t,s) \rVert_\infty = \max(\lvert t \rvert, \lvert s \rvert) \le 1 \}$ and $\bar S = \{ (t,s) \in \mathbb R^2 : \lVert (t,s) \rVert_\infty = 1 \}$. Also note that $\lvert t \rvert, \lvert s \rvert \le \sqrt{t^2 + s^2}$, thus $\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\infty \le \lVert (t,s) \rVert = $ Euclidean norm of $(t,s)$. Now define
$$\bar h : \bar D  \to D^2, \bar h(t,s) =   \begin{cases} \dfrac{\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\infty}{\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\phantom{\infty}}(t,s) & (t,s) \ne (0,0) \\ (0,0) & (t,s) \ne (0,0) \end{cases}$$
This map is well-defined because $\left\lVert  \dfrac{\lVert(t,s) \rVert_\infty}{\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\phantom{\infty}}(t,s) \right\rVert = \lVert(t,s) \rVert_\infty \le 1$. It is clearly continuous in all $(t,s) \ne (0,0)$. Continuity in $(0,0)$ follows from $\lVert \bar h(t,s) - \bar h(0,0) \rVert = \left\lVert  \dfrac{\lVert(t,s) \rVert_\infty}{\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\phantom{\infty}}(t,s) \right\rVert = \lVert(t,s) \rVert_\infty \le \lVert(t,s) \rVert$. Similarly
$$h^* : D^2  \to \bar D, h^*(t,s) =   \begin{cases} \dfrac{\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\phantom{\infty}}{\lVert (t,s) \rVert_\infty}(t,s) & (t,s) \ne (0,0) \\ (0,0) & (t,s) \ne (0,0) \end{cases}$$
is well-defined and it has the property $h^* \circ \bar h = id , \bar h \circ h^* = id$. Therefore $h$ is a bijection. But continuous bijections between compact Hausdorff spaces are homeomorphisms. Finally note that $\bar h(\bar S) = S^1$. Then $h = \bar h \circ \beta$ is the desired homeomorphism.

Comment: This is also valid for maps $S^n \to X$?