# Interpretation of fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I learned the concept of the fundamental group in Munkres where

> For a space $X$ and $x\in X$, the fundamental group is defined by $\pi_1(X,x)=\Omega(X,x)/\sim$ where $\Omega(X,x)=\{\gamma:[0,1]\to X:\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=x\}$ and $\sim$ is under homotopy.

I interpret it as different kinds of circles up to homotopy. However, on page 339 of Introduction of Topological Manifolds by John M. Lee it's been said that

> We can think of nontrivial elements of the fundamental group of a space X as equivalence classes of maps from the circle into X that do not extend to the disk.

My questions are: 1. the path $\gamma: I\to X$ is the same $\gamma':S^1\to X$. Is it because reparametrization preserves homotopy class? 2. What does it mean by not extending to a disk?

Comment: A homotopy of a loop to the constant loop determines an extension to the disk.

Comment: 1. That is because of the universal property of quotient space. 2. Once you can extend $S^1\to X$ to $D^1\to X$ then it implies $S^1\to X$ is nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not the *same*. However, we can identify the quotient space $I/\{0,1\}$ with the circle $S^1$. Hence each closed path $\gamma \in \Omega(X,x)$ induces a map $\gamma' : S^1 \to X$ such that $\gamma'(1) = x$. Concerning the assocation $\gamma \mapsto \gamma'$ have a look at [Characterizing simply connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044399) which explains that $\pi_1(X,x)$ can be identified with the set of pointed homotopy classes of pointed maps $(S^1,1) \to (X,x)$.
2. A pointed map $f : (S^1,1) \to (X,x)$ is pointed homotopic to the constant pointed map if and only if $f$ has an extension $F: D^2  \to X$. See again the answer to [Characterizing simply connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044399).