# in the sphere or disc,there is no essential simple closed curves?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, curves

How we can show in the sphere or disc,there is no essential simple closed curves ?

In the mapping class groups  By Benson farb , definition of essential closed curve is : a closed curve is called essential if it is not homotopic to a point, puncture, or a boundary component."

Comment: Did you study algebraic topology before reading that book? If you do, you will know how to prove that these spaces are simply-connected. If you did not study algebraic topology, read, say, the 1st chapter of Hatcher's book and make sure you solve exercises. Then continue reading the "Primer."

Comment: @MoisheKohan . Yes I know . In the Algebraic topology  by hatcher $ X$ is simply connected if has trivial fundumental group and path connected.  So why $X$ has no essential simple close curves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the sphere and disc are both simply connected.

Second, a path connected space $X$ is simply connected if and only if every continuous function $f : S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a point; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044399/characterizing-simply-connected-spaces).

Putting these together, since a simple closed curve is the image of a continuous function $f : S^1 \to X$, it follows that every simple closed curve is inessential.