# One question in Spanier's Algebraic Topology Theorem 1.4.12

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, product-space, cofibrations

In Spanier's Algebraic Topology Chapter 1 Section 4, he says that $Z_f \times I$ has the topology coinduced by the two maps as the following, which I do not understand:
[image]

Why $Z_f \times I$ equipped with the product topology has the topology coinduced ?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31697/when-is-the-product-of-two-quotient-maps-a-quotient-map). The point is that $Z_f\times I$ is a quotient of $X\times I\times I\sqcup Y\times I$.